# Binary Strings Question

Tags: combinatorics, binary

prove that the following expression for a set of binary strings S is ambigious
S = {101,1101,1011}*
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts on the problem and have tried some things you can share? Regards

Answer (score 5):

I don't see anything ambiguous about the expression. It's not standard mathematical notation, but as far as it's meant to denote the set of all strings that can be formed by concatenating any finite number of occurrences of 101, 1101 and 1011, it seems clear enough. My guess is that you mean you want to show that there are strings that can be formed in more than one way from these substrings. An example of such a string is afforded by 1011101, which is both 1011 101 and 101 1101.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

It is ambiguous because 1011101 (the binary which it can generate) can be generated in 2 different ways:

(101)(1101) and (1011)(101)

Thus, making this binary generation expression ambiguous.